# Can we reduce the crossing number of a graph by two by just removing only one edge?

Tags: graph-theory

I only know that if it is true, then there must be two edges crossing the same edge. Can you give me some hints or examples?

Comment: Wikipedia says that determining the crossing number is NP-hard even for near-planar graphs (i.e. graphs, that become planar after removing a single edge). This means that it is possible to reduce the crossing number by more than one by removing a single edge. I'd therefore try looking into near-planar graphs.

Answer (score 4):

[On the crossing number of planar graphs](https://www.ifisica.uaslp.mx/%7Egsalazar/RESEARCH/on-the-crossing-number-of-almost-planar-graphs.pdf) by Petr Hlinený and Gelasio Salazar has a construction for any crossing number.

Basically, take the polyhedron formed by sticking two $2n$-sided pyramids together base to base. Their edges form a planar graph, like any convex 3d polyhedron. If you add an edge between opposite vertices of the base, it becomes a graph with crossing number $n-1$. This is proved by induction in the paper (Proposition 3.1).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very non-constructive argument for the existence of $n$-vertex graphs where the deletion of one edge can reduce the crossing number by not just one or two, but $\Omega(n^2)$ crossings.

By the [crossing number inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossing_number_inequality), the complete graph $K_n$ has a crossing number of $\Omega(e^3/n^2) = \Omega(n^4)$. On the other hand, if you remove all $\binom n2$ edges, you get the empty graph, which has a crossing number of $0$.

As a result, if we remove the edges of $K_n$ one at a time, in arbitrary order, there must be at least one step at which the crossing number goes down by $\Omega(n^4)/\binom n2 = \Omega(n^2)$.